# How can I Initialize the state when using a stateless function to define my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use a stateless function to define my component, but that means I can't use life cycle methods like componentWillMount. So how can I render the component with initial content?

example of the above:

```
export const Panel = () => (<div></div>)
```

Comment: I guess using default properties? I am new to ReactJS too but just a thought ;)

Comment: I thought more a long the lines of populating the container with initial state, but can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess what I meant is mentioned in the answer below ;) I was searching the syntax for that :) :)

Comment: initialize the `state` for `stateless component`, if its statelesss then it wont have any any state ever, its just dumb component.  whose only job is to display some data, and if data not passed throw error or put default data. Nothing else.

Comment: you can pass it through a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default props like this:

```
export const Panel = ({name = 'Default user', age = 'N/A'}) => (
  <div>{name} {age}</div>
)
```

More about [destructuring objects](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/#default-values)

Comment: This is not valid syntax. Should be `({foo} = {foo: 'bar'}) => (<div>{foo}</div>)`